# Implementing operator overload outside class header in C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a GolfCourse class header gcourse.hh and I want to implement operator overload for >>operator. How do I do this outside the header in file gcourse.cc? That is, which "words" do I need to point to the class itself, "GolfCourse::" is not enough like for functions...?

```
gcourse.hh:
class GolfCourse {

public:
---
friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, GolfCourse& course);

gcourse.cc:
---implement operator>> here ---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GolfCourse::` is incorrect because `operator >>` isn't a member of `GolfCourse`. It's a free function. You'd just need to write:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, GolfCourse& course)
{
   //...
   return in;
}
```

The `friend` declaration in the class definition is only needed if you plan to access `private` or `protected` members from `GolfCourse`. You can, of course, provide the implementation inside the class definition:

```
class GolfCourse {
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, GolfCourse& course)
    {
       //...
       return in;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, now I can see that, I was just too stuck to implementing functions... Thank you!

Comment: Yep, I need to access private members of GolfCourse, so friend is needed.